# How to remove last fields using Unix commands

Tags: shell, unix

Example:

```
studid,firstname,lastname,dob,age
101,sunit,sharma,10-05-1980,30
102,sharma,raghu,12-05-1981
103,mayank,sexana
104,chiru,cherry,17-05-1988,26
105,mannu,srk
```

I want to  remove last fields of each row.
How to implement it using Unix commands?

Comment: Unix is an operating system. Different flavors of Unix have different utilities that can assist. You tagged the question with `python`--does that mean you actually want a python program to do this?

Comment: or you only forget what language do you using?

Comment: Some have three entries, some have four. Do you want to remove the fourth entry or the last one (for `105,mannu,srk`, the result should be `105,mannu,srk` or `105,mannu`)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the cut command from the command line `cut -d',' -f1-4 file/to/process`

`-d` sets the delimiter to ','

`-f1-4` tells it to give you back the first four fields, separated by the delimiter